# Assigning value to input field showing error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I am splitting a string from local storage and putting it in array as shown below:

`file.ts`

```
getskills: Array<string> = [];
// a,b,c is the value in getskills

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.getskills  = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("profskill")).split(',');
    console.log(this.getskills[1]);
    // The answer is b in  console window
  }
```

Now in my `file.html` I have an input field, I want its value to be `this.getskills[1]`  but when I assign this I get below error:

> Runtime Error
>   ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: ''. Current value: 'b'.

`file.html` code for reference:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-input [(ngModel)]="skills" type="text" #skills1 (keyup.enter)="save(skills1.value); skills1.value='' " placeholder="skills" [value] = "getskills[0] ? getskills[0]: ''"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

How can I assign that value to my input field?

Answer (score 0):

this will happen if your update has happened after Angular has checked the view.

quick and dirty way is ;

Inject the ChangeDetectorRef

```
constructor(private changeDetectorRef:ChangeDetectorRef){}

ionViewDidLoad() {
 this.getskills  = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("profskill")).split(',');
    console.log(this.getskills[1]);
    // The answer is b in  console window
     this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    // run the change detection manually
  }
```

But the right way to solve this sort of problem is to move your update(`ionViewDidLoad`) to a better moment.

Don't forget, when you make a change to the model ( `getskills'), you need to make sure Angular is aways of it.

EDIt :

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
     this.skills  = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("profskill")).split(',')[0];
        console.log(this.getskills[1]);
        // The answer is b in  console window
         this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
        // run the change detection manually
      }
```

and

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-input [(ngModel)]="skills" type="text" #skills1 (keyup.enter)="save(skills1.value); skills1.value='' " placeholder="skills"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: error is gone but still value is not loaded , i am using this code `[value] = "getskills[0] ? getskills[0]: ''"` , i can see result in my console `console.log(this.getskills[0]);`